# Request Path for Specified Store already exists in magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I want to link product to `"category page"` or `"products list page"`

I created a new Cateogy with name `"Category 1"` & Product with name `"Product1"`.

Url keys are `"cat1"` & `"Pro1"` respectively.

In `"URL REWRITE MANAGEMENT"`, I searched text `"pro1"` in `"Request path column"`.
`[Main website > Default wide > English ]`.

I got one result with `"Request path= "pro1.html"`.

I edit that and gave information as follows :

```
Type :system, 
store:english, 
Id path : product/177, 
request path : cat1.html, 
target path : catalog/product/view/id/177, 
redirect : permanent[301]
```

when i click on `"save"`, I got message as follows

Request Path for Specified Store already exists.

please help me to find solution.

Comment: The Request Path must be unique for each rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because request path for each store must be unique. For example if you have already set 'abc' for english store view then same record can not be added again. So I think request path 'cat1.html' for 'english' store view already exists. You can verify it again.